# Rails session is not changing value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4

consider the code below

```
def results
    params_list = []
    params.each_pair {|key, value|
      params_list.push([key,value])
    }
    p params_list
    session.delete(:image)
    p session[:image]
    @image = Gchart.pie_3d(:size => '500x300',
              :title => "Top 5 Results",
              :legend => ["#{params_list[0][0]} #{params_list[0][1]}%" , 'source-document2 [22%]','source-document3','source-document4','source-document5'],
              :data => [22, 21, 20, 18, 19])

    session[:image] = @image

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { head 200, content_type: "text/html" }
    end

  end

  def check_results

    if session[:image]
      @image = session[:image]
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

as you can see i delete the session[:image] and then reassign it. But when call it from the check_results action, i get the very first session i stored.

Why is that?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Also you should not use user input (the params) to create output without great care as it opens a XSS attack vulnerability.

Comment: @max i am sending a post request from python, i get some params which i want to pass in to the `GChart` to create a google chart - basically @image has a url at the end of the day. I store that in a session and by pressing a button on the index page, i want to load that @image (using remote: true) and show the graph. As for XSS attack its ok, this is just for a demo

Comment: I would not use sessions in this case. I would use a database backed model and stick to the RESTful defaults as it is deterministic and non-stateful. Rails by default uses cookies for session storage so you really should not put anything but simple scalars (numbers, strings) etc in the session storage.